# How implode array elements in php?

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, implode

How implode array element into single string in php

```
$name = array( 'id', "no", "date",'fadd');
echo  implode("','",$name);
```

I am looking for the output is

```
'id', 'no', 'date', 'fadd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the implode part right, just explicitly echo a quote before and after to get the leading and trailing characters:

```
$name = array( 'id', "no", "date",'fadd');
echo  "'" . implode("','",$name) . "'";
```