# Implode php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$Array = [
       [1, 33, 55, 18],
       [8, 9, 12, 67],
       [3, 33, 76, 88],
  ];
```

And I want add `;` to output like this:

```
1, 33, 55, 18; 
8, 9, 12, 67; 
3, 33, 76, 88
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How implode array elements in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874932/how-implode-array-elements-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array map to achieve this

```
$temp = array_map(function($item){
    return implode(", ", $item);
}, $Array);
foreach($temp as $v){
    // implode with ';' and \n for line break
    // you can use "<br/>" if you are using web.
    echo $v.";\n"; 
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/POn0r).

One looper:

```
foreach($Array as $v){
    echo implode(", ",$v).";\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0ERdZ).

**Output**

```
1, 33, 55, 18;
8, 9, 12, 67;
3, 33, 76, 88;
```