# Imploding json array in php file

Tags: php, json, implode

I'm trying to figure out how to implode a json array coming from an axios call, within a php file. I currently have this function where I toggle between dumping out the array and then trying to dump the imploded version but that fails stating that it's an invalid argument for a foreach.

PHP file:

```
public function getResults(array $num = []){
    dd($num);
    dd(implode(", ", array_map(function($obj) { foreach ($obj as $p => $v) { return $p;} }, $num)));
}
```

The dd($num) call shows this in my network console:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "{"number":"115"}"
  1 => "{"number":"135"}"
]
```

How can I implode this to look like `115,135`?

Comment: What and where is `dd()`'s function definition?

Comment: It's a dump and die statement, so the first one just dumps the array in my network console. If I comment it out the second one SHOULD dump the comma separated list in my network consoe but in this case it dumps an error

Comment: can you provide the **json** as a `string` or `encoded associative array` ?

Comment: @medilies it's coming from an axios call where the array is set via vue, so I'm just showing how it's coming through currently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How implode array elements in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25874932/how-implode-array-elements-in-php)

Comment: @gguney I tried that before but it prints: "{"number":"115"}','{"number":"135"}"

Comment: Can you add $num output in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php

function getResults(array $num = []): string
{
    return implode(", ", array_map(fn ($obj) => json_decode($obj)->number , $num));
}


$json = ['{"number":"115"}','{"number":"135"}'];

echo getResults($json);
```

Test https://3v4l.org/HUmuM

## Issues with your code

1. PHP receives JSON as a string. So you **need to decode** that string so it makes sense for your code as a data structure.
2. You have an array of objects. `array_map` **already iterates** through the array and exposes the **stringified objects** inside its scope. So I see no need for the extra loop.
3. Even if you did decode the object as an **associative array** you could just do `return $obj['number']`. `($obj as $p => $v) { return $p;}` would always return `"number"` which is the key.

---

#### Fix for the comment feedback

> My code is throwing an error at => (I'm running PHP 7.1)

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' in...

https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php

> Arrow functions were introduced in PHP 7.4 as a more concise syntax for anonymous functions.

```php
return implode(", ", array_map(function ($obj) {
    return json_decode($obj)->number;
}, $num));
```

Comment: Ok this definitely works in that test but my code is throwing an error at => (I'm running PHP 7.1), do you know how that would be conveted?

Comment: That is probably caused by the usage of the arrorw function `fn()=>`, replace it with the traditional callback format

Answer (score 1):

You should use php's built in function json_decode($data) to decode json.

You Will not get it in the format you have show, but as a stdClass by default.

If you oass a 2nd argument to json_decode (true or false) you will get it as and associative array og you are more comdortable with that.

I would have provided a better usage example, but the editor is not coorporating on my mobile device.